# GORM Eagerly Fetch Collection With Criteria

Tags: grails, join, groovy, criteria, eager-loading

I have a simple one-to-many association:

```
class Foo {
    int id
    Date someDate

    static hasMany = [
        bars: Bar
    ]
}

class Bar {
    Foo foo
    Date someDate

    static mapping = {
        .....
        columns {
            foo([:]) {
                column name: "id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Under normal circumstances, calling foo.bars will return all Bars, which is fine.  But in this case I need to query using the `someDate` argument.  I need to eagerly fetch the collection, but I'm not sure how to do this.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
Foo.withCriteria {
    eq("id", someId)
    bars {
        eq("someDate", ?????)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in for the value though, since it's not known ahead of time, or if there's a better way to do it?

Comment: You would put the variable there???

Comment: @JamesKleeh I think you missed the question.  I wanted to join Bars and Foo by not only the PK but also on another Date field.  So where the "?????" is, I didn't know what to put there in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering the list inside the parent class would be very confusing. If you managed to make an instance `foo` where `foo.bars` only had a subset of the list of `Bar`s, things like `foo.addToBars` would have strange behavior, among other problems.

If you merely need to find the set of `Bar`s that belong to a given `Foo`, filtered by their `someDate` property, you should be querying against the `Bar` class to begin with:

```
Bar.findAllByFooAndSomeDate(foo, dateVal)
Bar.findAllByFooAndSomeDateBetween(foo, startDate, endDate)
```

or:

```
Bar.findAll() {
    (foo.id == someId) && (someDate == dateVal)
}
```

etc.

Comment: There is a lot more to the query, I just reduced it for simplicity.  I'm just trying to populate the object graph in a single query (if possible?) instead of doing multiple queries for each set I need filtered.  What I just want to do is to fetch that collection based on the parent object's someDate property.  But, your comment makes sense, where doing things with the list would be weird.

Comment: If you're populating a complex graph, you're probably better off with HQL and projections.